# Anonymous method shortest syntax

Tags: c#, func, anonymous-methods

Regarding anonymous methods, and given a method "WriteConditional" that has the first parameter as a Func, is there a way to even eliminate the extra "() => " syntax?

It seems like you should be able to, since its unambiguous as long as there's no additional overload that would accept string, right?

```
void Program()
{
  IDictionary<string,string> strings = new Dictionary<string,string>() { {"test","1"},{"test2","2"}};

  //seems like this 'should' work, because WriteConditional has no other overload
  //that could potentially make this ambiguous
  WriteConditional(strings["test"],"<h3>{0}</h3>");

  //since WriteConditional_2 has two overloads, one that has Func<string> and another with string,
  //the call could be ambiguous, so IMO you'd definitely have to "declare anonymous" here:
  WriteConditional_2(()=>strings["test"],"<h3>{0}</h3>");      
}

void WriteConditional(Func<string> retriever, string format)
{
   string value = retriever.Invoke();
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)==false)
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format(format,value));
}

void WriteConditional_2(Func<string> retriever, string format)
{
   string value = retriever.Invoke();
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)==false)
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format(format,value));
}

void WriteConditional_2(string value, string format)
{
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)==false)
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format(format,value));
}
```

Comment: `is there a way to even eliminate the extra "() => " syntax?` WHY (if I'm reading your question correctly)?  That syntax specifically means *anonymous method*.  Anyone who reads it, understands it. Eliminating it means I can't tell which method signature I'd call, or what it's trying to do.

Comment: Well, that syntax specifically means "lambda expression". `delegate { return strings["test"]; }` would be an anonymous method.

Comment: Can you please comment on how "...like this 'should' work, " - what is your expected behavior of converting `string` into a function?

Comment: Of course any lambda with any parameters is of course obviously taken out of consideration here, as you'd have no name for the parameter to be able to use it.  That cuts out the vast majority of actual uses of lambdas.

Comment: This would require the compiler to look ahead a very large amount before it even knew what it was parsing. It also means that you cannot tell whether `foo(a)` is an immediate or delayed evaluation purely by syntax.

Comment: @RaymondChen isn't this what the parse tree is for?  Either way, you end up with a method that returns a string, only difference is when the method is executed, and the LINQ methods frequently make this vague as well... for instance Linq-2-Sql delays execution of ".Where(x=>x.Id==1)" all the way until a direct .GetEnumerator() call that would require the expression tree to finally be turned-into-sql, executed, and return a result.

Comment: The point I am not doing a good job of making is that the decision whether something is a lambda or not can no longer be determined purely syntactically. This makes parsing hard both for computers and humans.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, there is no such way. You could however, cheat and provide your own overload:

```
void WriteConditional(Func<string> retriever, string format)
{
   var value = retriever();
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)==false)
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format(format,value));
}

void WriteConditional(string value, string format)
{
   WriteConditional(() => value, format);
}
```

Comment: That's semantically different.  It's evaluating the expression to its value immediately rather than closing over the variables and deferring execution until the delegate is invoked.

Comment: @Servy Correct. As I said, it's cheating, it's not quite the same. That's why my answer was "No" :)

Comment: A little disappointing, but understandable... since if a new overload for WriteConditional was created that took string as 1st parameter, there'd be a semantic change to the operation.  Just seems like the compiler should be able to coerce a method that returns string into a Func<string> instance easily.

Comment: @enorl76 It would create some spectacular bugs, since it would mean that you might pass an expression, not realizing that its execution is deferred. It would no longer be possible to tell whether an expression is evaluated immediately or not just by looking at it.

Comment: @RaymondChen I can agree with your first statement, but most of the LINQ methods frequently are vague about the exact time that statements are being run, I don't see how this is different...

Comment: In practice, this is what I ended up doing, but cannot do this for existing methods that take String type as inputs.  Seems like the compiler should be able to make that assumption for you.  And I do understand the design decision: the explicit nature of C# versus implicit.

Comment: @enorl76 LINQ has its own syntax so there is no overloading of existing syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
is there a way to even eliminate the extra "() => " syntax?
```

I also think the answer is no but you can do something if your func returns a custom class by using operator overloading.
This could be possible for other types if you could use operation overloading with extention methods

```
using System;

public class MyClass
{
   public static implicit operator Func<MyClass>(MyClass obj)
   {
     return () => { Console.WriteLine("this is another cheat"); return new MyClass(); };
   }
}


public class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {

      MyClass x = new MyClass();
      WriteConditional(x);
      Console.ReadLine();
   }

   static void WriteConditional(Func<MyClass> retriever) {  }

}
```